# Number of symmetric relations on a set with n elements?

Tags: combinatorics

I cannot figure out why the following method to calculate the number of elements in a set with n elements is wrong:

$N = \text{Total} - \text{not symmetric} = 2^{n^2}- 2^{n(n-1)}$

$n\times(n-1)$ because $n$ choices for a and hence $(n-1)$ choices for b in a non symmetric relation with (a,b).

Can anyone point the flaw in the solution and suggest the right way to do it using complement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you are substracting is not the number of non-symmetric relations, I think you are counting relations thar are totally non-reflexive (I just invented this term). In other words you are counting the relations such that $a\not\sim a$ for every $a$.

The number of relations that are not symmetric is not that easy to count directly I think.

However, we can count the number of symmetric relations. Firstly we must select whether $a\sim a$ for every $a$ and secondly we must decide for each unordered pair $\{a,b\}$ if $a\sim b$ and $b\sim a$ ( remember that one implies the other and vice versa).

Hence there are $n+ \binom{n}{2} = n(n+1)/2$ decisions, and so there are $2^{n(n+1)/2}$ symmetric relations.